# javascript to limit form options on multiple level children inputs

Tags: javascript, forms, bootstrap-4

I have the following form, in summary:

kingdom --> phylum --> class --> order --> family --> genus...

If the `kingdom = Animalia` then the `phylum` options should be a certain list.

Following on, if the `phylum` then = `Chordata` the next drop down input option should be a certain list.

To continue, if the `class` = `Mammalia` the next drop down input option should be a certain list... etc.

So a hierarchical form with many dependant levels.

I've looked and tried a few examples, but I can't find a way to do this. Any ideas/suggestions?

Here's the bootstrap html:

```
              <div class='col-12 left'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <label for='uname'>kingdom</label>
                  <!-- <input type='text' class='form-control' name='kingdom' value ='Animalia' placeholder='Animalia' > -->


                  <select class="form-control" name='kingdom'>
                    <option>Animalia</option>
                    <option>Plantae</option>
                    <option>Fungi</option>
                    <option>Protista</option>
                    <option>Monera</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
                  <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class='col-12 left'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <label for='uname'>phylum/division</label>
                  <!-- <input type='text' class='form-control' name='phylum' value ='Chordata' placeholder='Chordata' > -->
                  <select class="form-control" name='phylum'>
                    <option>Chordata</option>
                    <option>Annelid</option>
                    <option>Arthropod</option>
                    <option>Bryozoa</option>
                    <option>Cnidaria</option>
                    <option>Echinoderm</option>
                    <option>Mollusc</option>
                    <option>Nematode</option>
                    <option>Platyhelminthes</option>
                    <option>Rotifer</option>
                    <option>Sponge</option>

                  </select>
                  <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
                  <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class='col-12 left'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <label for='uname'>class</label>
                  <!-- <input type='text' class='form-control' name='class' value ='Mammalia' placeholder='Mammalia' > -->
                  <select class="form-control" name='class'>
                    <option>Mammalia</option>
                    <option>Aves</option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
                  <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class='col-12 left'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <label for='uname'>order</label>
                  <!-- <input type='text' class='form-control' name='order' value ='Artiodactyla' placeholder='Artiodactyla' > -->
                  <select class="form-control" name='order'>
                    <option>Artiodactyla</option>
                    <option>Aegotheliformes</option>
                    <option>Perissodactyla</option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
                  <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class='col-12 left'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <label for='uname'>family</label>
                  <!-- <input type='text' class='form-control' name='family' value ='Bovidae' placeholder=' Bovidae' > -->
                  <select class="form-control" name='family'>
                    <option>Bovidae</option>
                    <option>Aegothelidae</option>
                    <option>Equidae</option>
                    <option>Delphinidae</option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
                  <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class='col-12 left'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <label for='uname'>genus</label>
                  <input type='text' class='form-control' name='genus' value ='Capra' placeholder='Capra' > 
                  <select class="form-control" name='genus'>
                    <option>Capra</option>
                    <option>Ovis</option>
                    <option>Aegotheles</option>
                    <option>Oreamnos</option>
                    <option>Equus</option>
                    <option>Orcinus</option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
                  <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class='col-12 left'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <label for='uname'>subgenus</label>
                  <input type='text' class='form-control' name='subgenus' value ='Capra (aegagrus) hircus' placeholder='Capra (aegagrus) hircus' >

                  <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
                  <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class='col-12 left'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <label for='uname'>elementName</label>
                  <!-- <input type='text' class='form-control' name='elementName' value ='a' placeholder='' > -->
                  <select class="form-control" name='elementName'>
                    <option>Cranium</option>
                    <option>Mandible</option>
                    <option>Teeth</option>
                    <option>Rib</option>
                    <option>Humerus</option>
                    <option>Ulna</option>
                    <option>Radius</option>
                    <option>Carpal</option>
                    <option>Metacarpal</option>
                    <option>Femur</option>
                    <option>Patela</option>
                    <option>Fibula</option>
                    <option>Tarsal</option>
                    <option>Metatarsal</option>
                    <option>Scapula</option>
                    <option>Vertebrae</option>
                    <option>Middle Phalanx</option>
                    <option>Phalanx</option>
                    <option>Tibia</option>
                    <option>Astragalus</option>
                    <option>Calcaneus</option>
                    <option>Proximal Phalanx</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
                  <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe little bit lazy, but it works
if you thought similar

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <select class="form-control" id="sel0">
        <option value="0">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">Audi</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select class="form-control dispnone" id="sel1_1">
        <option value="0">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">A4</option>
        <option value="2">RS8</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control dispnone" id="sel1_2">
        <option value="0">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">E36</option>
        <option value="2">X5</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control dispnone" id="sel2_1">
        <option value="0">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">120LE</option>
        <option value="2">140LE</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control dispnone" id="sel2_2">
        <option value="0">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">cyl8</option>
        <option value="2">cyl16</option>
    </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var select_nums = 3;
        $("#sel0").change(function() {
            var ch = $("#sel0").val();
            if(ch==0){
                for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
                    $('#sel1_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
                }
                $('#sel1_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
            }else if(ch==1){
                for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
                    $('#sel1_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
                }
                  $('#sel1_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
            }else if(ch==2){
                for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
                    $('#sel1_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
                }
                $('#sel1_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
            }
        });

        $("#sel1_1").change(function() {
            var ch = $("#sel1_1").val();
            if(ch==0){
                for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
                    $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
                }
                $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
            }else if(ch==1){
                for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
                    $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
                }
                $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
            }else if(ch==2){
                for (var i = 1; i < select_nums; i++) {
                    $('#sel2_'+i).css({'display':'none'});
                }
                $('#sel2_'+ch).css({'display':'block'});
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like it will do the job, just testing it.

Comment: So, that work wonderfully... except... the `value` is submitted, not the text in the drop down, is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I extracted a portion of your html and got it working using an event listener to hide the unwanted options. I hope it helps:

I only considered the first two categories to show the example 'Animalia' and 'Plantae' and considered two subsets of options for each. The change event on the select tag triggers the code to hide and show as required.

```js
function hideSubset(selectedValue){
    
    let secondChoice = document.querySelector('#secondChoice');
    let firstChoice = document.querySelector('#firstChoice');

    if (selectedValue === 'Animalia'){
        
        secondChoice.style.display = 'none';
        firstChoice.style.display = 'block';
        
    } else {
        
        firstChoice.style.display = 'none';
        secondChoice.style.display = 'block';
    }
}


let mainChoice = document.querySelector('#mainChoice');

mainChoice.addEventListener('change', function(){
    hideSubset(mainChoice.value);
}, false);
```

```html
<div class='col-12 left'>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label for='uname'>kingdom</label>
      <!-- <input type='text' class='form-control' name='kingdom' value ='Animalia' placeholder='Animalia' > -->


      <select class="form-control" name='kingdom' id="mainChoice">
        <option>Choose one</option>
        <option>Animalia</option>
        <option>Plantae</option>   
      </select>
      <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
      <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='col-12 left' id="firstChoice">
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label for='uname'>Options for Animalia</label>
      <!-- <input type='text' class='form-control' name='phylum' value ='Chordata' placeholder='Chordata' > -->
      <select class="form-control" name='phylum'>
        <option>Chordata</option>
        <option>Annelid</option>
        <option>Arthropod</option>
        <option>Bryozoa</option>
        <option>Cnidaria</option>
        <option>Echinoderm</option>

      </select>
      <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
      <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='col-12 left' id="secondChoice">
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label for='uname'>Options for Plantae</label>
      <!-- <input type='text' class='form-control' name='phylum' value ='Chordata' placeholder='Chordata' > -->
      <select class="form-control" name='phylum'>
        <option>Mollusc</option>
        <option>Nematode</option>
        <option>Platyhelminthes</option>
        <option>Rotifer</option>
        <option>Sponge</option>

      </select>
      <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
      <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It shows like this on my side. I use bootstrap 4

[Looks like this when loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sydzC.png)

[When choosing Animalia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPdqB.png)

[When choosing Plantae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vXHa.png)